# Grails: How to select specific value from domain

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I have an id that I need to use to query another id.

```
select id2 from mytable where id2 = id1 --id1 is preloaded from another db
```

How do I do that with a Grails Domain? I'm assuming it would be something like this, but how do I get the specific value I need, like in a where clause?

```
package myapp

class MyId(id1) {
    int id2

    static mapping = {
        table "mytable"

        id2 column: "id2"
        version false
    }   
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would do the querying in a service or a controller, not in the domain class itself. Your domain class then looks like this:

```
package myapp

class MyId {
    int id2
    static mapping = {
        table "mytable"
        version false
    }
}
```

and you would query it simply using `MyId.findAllById2(id1)`

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to get the record with the id given.. you can simply use

```
def result = your_Domain_Class_Package.Your_DomainClass_Name.get(id)
```

your result variable will be having the results of your interest